# Generate new menus at timed intervals

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am thinking to incorporate a certain type of menu system in my silverlight application window.

```
______
|_____|
|_____|
|_____|
|_____|
|_____|
```

The menu options keep on changing at cetain times. Let's say at 3 sec, I have 3 different options, and at 5 seconds, I might have 5 different options.

I am generating these options in the form of a collection of labels. 
Each label object item in this collection will have a different content, different OnClick behaviour etc.

What would be a decent way to change these previous menu options with the new collection of buttons, (with some cool storyboarding as well - secondary thing in this case)?
whenever I generate a new collection at a new time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate new menus at time intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977818/generate-new-menus-at-time-intervals)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Another collaborator of mine posted the same thing. Deleted that post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind off the top of my head...

1. Set up XML files that contain the layout for your menus, and use if statements to bind to a different one during different times of the day.
2. Do the same basic things, but with data in a database.  Have your menu structure contained within a database, and have each menu be assigend for a date/time. Use SLQ to select the appropriate menu based on the time of day.

Comment: Can you explain the first option in a bit more detail. How are the menu layouts defined through XML files, and binded acccording the number of items?

Comment: I'm assuming you know what you want in the menu at certain time intervalce, correct?  If so, then you create a different XML file for each time interval.  a.xml, b.xml, c.xml or whatever naming scheme you come up with.  Then, in code, where you generate the menus, use an if statement.  If DateTime.Now > 8:00 AM and < 8:05 AM then use a.xml, etc.  Google should turn up dozens if not hundreds of results on how to use an XML file to define a menu.  You just need to plan accordingly and adjust as necessary.

Comment: Also, curious as to what you've already tried.  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

If you use a separate control to represent each menu item, you can use an ItemsControl in your application window, and bind to an ObservableCollection of the ViewModel that backs your menu item control.  Then you could have a class that adds and removes MenuItems based on any type of business logic you'd like, and your main view will always reflect these changes.  The actual dates and times can be stored any way you want, with the best two options probably being a config file or database entries (as mentioned by David Stratton).